# How to embed a ranking function into the AllPrevious Function for a calculated column in Spotfire

Tags: calculated-columns, ranking, spotfire

I am trying to make one equation from the two below, but either I am missing something completely simple, or there is a trick to embedding a ranking function into the "AllPrevious" function in Spotfire

VAR_X = (Rank([D] / [A],"desc",[B],"ties.method=first"))

VAR_Y = Sum([A] * [C]) OVER (intersect([B],AllPrevious([VAR_X])))

I am trying to essentially do (bypassing the creation of VAR_X:

VAR_Y = Sum([A] * [C]) OVER (intersect([B],AllPrevious(((Rank([D] / [A],"desc",[B],"ties.method=first"))))))

I keep getting an error message anytime I put something after "AllPrevious(" and I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the limitation is that you cannot put functions inside an OVER. You would have to define Rank(...) as a calculated column first as you did before

Comment: @GaiaPaolini that's what I was thinking, thanks for confirming...definitely a bummer that we do that!